# How do I inject services into a HostedService without using a ScopeFactory?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

Most solutions I've found for this question involve using an `IServiceScopeFactory` to inject scoped services into a hosted service. I don't want to do this because it makes testing difficult. It'd be nice to inject the services I need into my hosted service using an `IServicesCollection`, just like `Startup.cs`. Ideally something like this:

```
# Program.cs
...
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>();
    services.AddSingleton<IOtherInjectedService, OtherInjectedService>();
    services.AddScoped<MyService>(); // <-- how does this work?
    services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
});

# MyHostedService.cs
public class MyHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly MyService _svc;

    public MyHostedService(MyService svc) 
    {
        _svc = svc;
    }

    public void DoWork() {
        _svc.Work();
    }
}

# MyService.cs
public class MyService
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;
    private readonly IOtherInjectedService _otherService;

    public void Work()
    {
        _otherService.Foo(_context);
    }
}
```

This falls apart when I try to configure the services in `Program.cs`. What I see is this error:

```
Cannot consume scoped service 'MyService' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.
```

Which makes sense -- a singleton cannot consume a scoped service. But it looks like there is no way to make `IHostedService` scoped. Does that mean there is no way to inject dependencies without using a scope factory? I hope not! It makes testing difficult, to say the least.

What is the right way to inject services into a hosted service *without* using an `IServiceScopeFactory`?

Comment: You can register this service as `Transient`: `services.AddTransient<MyService>();` if it is suitable in your scenario.

Comment: But then you will need to register your `MyContext`  as transient also (via parameter in `AddDbContext`) and depended on your usage scenario it can introduce problems.